# MAGMI CLI warning timezone

Tags: magento, timezone, magmi

Does anybody know why I get this warning message when launching a Magmi import via CLI?

PHP Warning:  strftime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Dublin' for 'IST/1.0/DST' instead in /var/www/vhosts/negozi-linklibri.com/httpdocs/master/magmii/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php on line 400

My php time settings are correct, in fact I don't see that warning in the web GUI anymore.

thanks

Comment: It may surely be due to the fact that your php.ini for "web applications" is not the same that is used for cli. It really depends on the host system.

Comment: fixed. date.timezone in main (server side) php.ini was blank on my dedicated server. CLI version doesn't run according to website (domain) php.ini like the web interface does instead